# Installing some programs and games

Tags: ppa, repository

I'm trying to install some programs like Runescape with the (terminal) but I get 404 error. I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm adding PPA (and try to get `sudo apt-get update`) but it fails to download and get following errors.

```
W:The repository '-http://ppa.launchpad.net/hikariknight/unix-runescape-client/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file 
data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use 
    W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:Failed to fetch  
ppa.launchpad.net/hikariknigh...amd64/Packages 404 Not Found 
E:Failed to fetch //ppa.launchpad.net/hikariknigh...-i386/Packages 404 Not Found 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

Comment: This is because the repository for Ubuntu 16.04 is empty!. I have opened an issue regarding this problem of yours. HikariKnight has replied that the repository will be updated soon. All you have to do now is wait for the repository to come alive and follow this thread : **[Void Repository #97](https://github.com/HikariKnight/rsu-client/issues/97#issuecomment-217812300)**

Answer (score 1):

The discussed [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~hikariknight/+archive/ubuntu/unix-runescape-client) does not support 16.04 so far. Last supported version right now is Wily - aka 15.10 according to the Launchpad side listing.

Therefor contact the ppa maintainer and ask for updates or wait until he does it by himself.